# Tomcat crashes JVM due to EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: tomcat, crash, jvm

After some time away from work, it seems that one of my colleagues decided to experiment with our staging server. With the objeticve of developing using a new framework for DB access, he installed a bunch of stuff without being careful if there was any unwanted interaction with the in house developed applications.

Instead of having any kind of framework to handle the SQL calls from the JSP apps, the old DBA/Programmer wrote a crude connection class to access the MS-SQL'08 server. The class in question is gone, we don't have the source code for it.

So when I come back to work and try to stage a new developing application I managed to crash the JVM, here's the dump file.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006f19137c, pid=692, tid=6096
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_75-b13) (build 1.7.0_75-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.75-b04 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x12137c]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\hs_err_pid692.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

The whole dump file is available at: pastebin.com/TtgdkLer

What did I try to do:

- Remove everything that was added later.
- Check all server config files for anything out of the ordinary
- Copy the last backup image of the Tomcat folder + application data
- Do a fresh install of Tomcat 7 and reconfigure everything from scratch

Nothing works.

What I did find out is that on the major application web.xml there's a filter that if I remove, won't crash the server:

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ConnectionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

The problem is that this particular filter routes the connections through the authentication server. Meaning that turning it off would allow any user to access the information on the Intranet.

I'm honestly out of options. The last option I have is to rewind the state of the whole server back to a whole while ago. Any suggestions?

Comment: `1.7.0_75`, that's not the latest java version, it may have already been fixed if it's a jvm bug, try updating.

Comment: Shouldn't I be worried that it could break something else on the server?

Comment: That's a possibility. But you have to ask yourself whether that possibility is worse than an already-known-to-occur crash.

Comment: which version did you update to?

Comment: The lastest available at Oracles website: 8u45

Comment: Can you add the new crashlog? to see if anything changed.

Comment: I compared to the original one, only the VM version has changed. I'm trying to restore the state of the server to an ealier state at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash report has the the following method at the top of the stack:
`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.SNISecGenClientContext([B[I[BI[B[I[ZLjava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/logging/Logger;)I+0`

---

Edit: Original answer obsolete

Comment: Yeap. That was it. It seems the .dll for the SQL connection was wrong on the server.

Comment: Why do you think the crash is related to JIT compilation when `hs_err.log` explicitly shows that all methods on the stack have been executed in interpreter (small `j`)? The problem has happened at application startup in VM runtime code during the *linking* of JNI method, possibly because of bad native library.

Comment: @apangin, you're right. It was late, I must have read that backwards. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have encountered the same issue again when migrating the server again, but this time as I changed the DLL the issue was not resolved or changed at all.

I'm just adding that the actual JAR file was from a different package and that was enough to cause the same error, when I downloaded and installed the correct JAR/DLL combination, everything was fine.